# On a question regarding Zeta function integral similar to Balazard, Saias ,Yor integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Consider the following integral:

> $$I(t,a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\log|\zeta(it)|}{1+at²}dt$$

where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

We can see this integral similar to that of Balazard Saias Yor integral

> How to  get value of this type of integral?

> What significance this has if we could calculate its exact value in the context of prime number theory ?

Answer (score 1):

For $a>0$, using the functional equation $\zeta(s)=f(s)\zeta(1-s)$ you get two integrals
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log |\zeta(it)|}{1+at^2}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log |f(it)|}{1+at^2}dt+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log |\zeta(1-it)|}{1+at^2}dt$$

The second one is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log |\zeta(1-it)|}{1+at^2}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log \zeta(1-it)}{1+at^2}dt=2i\pi \frac{\log \zeta(1+a^{-1/2})}{2 i a^{1/2}}$$ using the residue theorem, which is valid since $\frac{\log \zeta(1-it)}{1+at^2}$ is integrable on the real axis, it is analytic and it decreases fast enough on the upper half-plane away from a simple pole at $i a^{-1/2}$ of residue $\frac{\log \zeta(1+a^{-1/2})}{2 i a^{1/2}}$.

I don't know how to evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log |f(it)|}{1+at^2}dt$$

From $\pi/\sin(\pi s)=\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)$ we get that
$\pi/|\sin(\pi it)| = |\Gamma(it) \Gamma(1-it)|=|\Gamma(1-it) |^2/ |t|$

so that $|\Gamma(1-it)| = \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{|\sin(\pi it)|^{1/2}} |t|^{1/2}$ and $\log |f(it)| = \log (\pi^{-1/2}/2) +\log |\sin(\pi it/2)|-\frac12\log |\sin(\pi it)|+\frac12 \log|t|$. Two terms can be integrated with the residue theorem, it remains to find $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log \left|\frac{\sin^2(\pi it/2)}{\sin(\pi it)}\right| \frac{dt}{1+at^2}$. Integration by parts and residue theorem? It should give a residue at $ia^{-1/2}$  plus something like $\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^n \Im(\log (1- \frac{ia^{-1/2}}{n})-\log (1+ \frac{ia^{-1/2}}{n}))$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @renus can you also mention, if possible, what could be it's significance if we could calculate this exactly?